# VPN Connection Dies Every 31 Minutes

Tags: networking, vpn, macos-sierra

I use a PPTP VPN server to log into the network of my academic lab (I know this is insecure; the choice of protocol is beyond my control). I've been using the VPN client Shimo to connect my OS X machine since Sierra dropped PPTP support, but there's a weird pattern of failures that I can't isolate the cause of.

The connection fails every 34.1 minutes, but it seems to be an interaction of the client and the router or ISP that I'm using. The connection is stable from my home (serviced by Comcast) with a Mac OS 10.10 machine, but not Shimo on 10.12. Shimo maintains a connection from other locations (coffeeshops, elsewhere on the university campus). There are no errors on the server; on the client I always see something like:

```
2016/10/22 14:45:46:862  Shimo detected a change of network configurations.
2016/10/22 15:18:51:554  no echo-reply, start ppp_auxiliary_probe!
2016/10/22 15:19:51:700  no echo-reply, despite successful ppp_auxiliary_probe!
2016/10/22 15:19:51:700  No response to 3 echo-requests
2016/10/22 15:19:51:701  Serial link appears to be disconnected.
2016/10/22 15:19:51:702  Connection terminated.
```

If I disconnect, I can reconnect to the VPN server immediately.

My question isn't "what's wrong with my setup" but rather what am I missing about VPN connections: why would the combination of client and network matter?